# AWS CDK: Conditional resources?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a cron event that runs daily on the `PROD` environment and just once a week on the `DEV` environment.  My code looks like this,

```
environment = CfnParameter(
    self,
    "environment",
    type="String",
    description="Environment e.g. DEV|PROD",
    default="DEV",
    allowed_values=["DEV", "PROD"],
)

if environment.value_as_string == "PROD":

    rule = events.Rule(
        self,
        "Some clever description",
        schedule=events.Schedule.cron(minute="0", hour="2", week_day="TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT"),
    )
else:
    rule = events.Rule(
        self,
        "Some clever description",
        schedule=events.Schedule.cron(minute="0", hour="2", week_day="TUE"),
    )
```

My issue is that on my prod account when I check the cloudformation parameters its showing `PROD` however the event is only running once a week?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach isn't working because you can't use deploy-time CloudFormation Parameters with native `if..then` code.

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html): Because they are not available at synthesis time, parameter values cannot be easily used for flow control and other purposes in your CDK app... To do control flow with parameters, you can use `CfnCondition` constructs, although this is awkward compared to native if statements.

Here are two more idiomatic CDK approaches.  In both cases, the answer to "prod or dev?" is known at synth-time:

#### Option 1:  Add a `prod: bool` prop to your Stack definition

One approach, taken from the CDK [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html), uses a Stack prop and `if prod:` control flow statement.

```py
# app.py
MyStack(app, "beta", env=my_dev_env)
MyStack(app, "prod", prod=True, env=my_prod_env)
```

#### Option 2: Use the Stack's account id for control flow

You may not need an explicit `prod` prop.  Another approach, also presented in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html), would be to use the stack's account id to determine the conditional variable:

```py
#MyStack.py

if self.account == '<prod-account>':
    # do prod stuff
else:
    # do dev stuff
```

With either approach, depending on your deployment strategy, you could separate the apps into two files (e.g. `app_prod.py`, `app_dev.py`).  The main points here are: [make decisions at synthesis time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-synth) and [model all production stages in code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-stages).